# Jquery: If radio button A is checked, do this. If B is check, do this

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, radio-button

I have the following jQuery code implemented:

```
var $morning = $(".radiobox .bba, .radiobox .mba");
var $evening = $(".radiobox .mba");

$('.radiobox input.morneve').change(function(){
    if ($(".radiobox input[value='Morning']").is(':checked')) {
        $($morning).attr("enabled");
    }
    if (!$(".radiobox input[value='Morning']").is(':checked')) {
        $($morning).attr("disabled");
    }
    if ($(".radiobox input[value='Evening']").is(':checked')) {
        $($evening).attr("enabled");
    }
    if (!$(".radiobox input[value='Evening']").is(':checked')) {
        $($evening).attr("disabled");
    }
});
```

And this is the HTML:

```
<div class="radiobox">
    <input type="radio" name="morneve" class="morneve" value="Morning">
</div>
<div class="radiobox">
    <input type="radio" name="morneve" class="morneve" value="Evening">
</div>
<hr />
<div class="radiobox">
    <input type="radio" name="degreq" class="degreg bba" value="bba">
</div>
<div class="radiobox">
    <input type="radio" name="degreq" class="degreg mba" value="mba">
</div>
```

What I'm trying to do is, if input Morning is checked, then the $morning should be enabled. If input Evening is selected, then $morning should be disabled and $evening should be enabled.

It all works fine, except for the overlapping class .mba

When I check Morning, I see morning ones enabled. When I check Evening, only .mba is enabled. But if I click back on Morning, .mba also gets disabled.

I've been spending hours working on this, I'm sure I'm missing something... Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: have a look at `.prop(prop, bool)` method

Comment: With one argument, `.attr()` retrieves the value, it doesn't set it.

Comment: There is no `enabled` property, just `disabled`. Set it to `true` or `false` depending on what you want.

Comment: just show your html also, its not clearly understandable format.

Comment: Have included the HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this fixed and working using the following code:

```
$('.radiobox input.morneve').change(function(){
    if ($(".radiobox input[value='Morning']").is(':checked')) {
        $(".degreg").attr("disabled", true);
        $($morning).removeAttr("disabled");
        $($evening).prop('checked', false);
    }
    if ($(".radiobox input[value='Evening']").is(':checked')) {
        $(".degreg").attr("disabled", true);
        $($evening).removeAttr("disabled");
        $($morning).prop('checked', false);
    }
});
```

What it's doing is first disabling all inputs with class .degreg and then removing the disabled attribute from the $morning / $evening ones. Works fine, thought I'd post it here so it helps someone.

Thanks to everyone who contributed!

Answer (score 1):

There is no attribute called `enabled`

```js
// Basically this Morning and Evening are times for when classes are offered. MBA option is offered in both
$(function() {
  var $bba = $(".radiobox .bba");
  var $mba = $(".radiobox .mba");
    
  $('.radiobox input.morneve').click(function(){
    $($bba).prop("disabled",$(".radiobox input[value='Evening']").is(':checked'));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="radiobox">
    <label><input type="radio" name="morneve" class="morneve" value="Morning">Morning</label>
</div>
<div class="radiobox">
    <label><input type="radio" name="morneve" class="morneve" value="Evening">Evening</label>
</div>
<hr />
<div class="radiobox">
    <label><input type="radio" name="degreq" class="degreg bba" value="bba">BBA</label>
</div>
<div class="radiobox">
    <label><input type="radio" name="degreq" class="degreg mba" value="mba">MBA</label>
</div>
```

Comment: This does the same thing. Works fine but if I check Evening and then go back to Morning, .mba is disabled.

Comment: So you need to explain better why you have mba in both

Comment: Basically this Morning and Evening are times for when classes are offered. MBA option is offered in both... hence it's in both.